Because project depends on flutter_lints any which doesn't exist (authorization failed), version solving failed
Since yesterday, every time I run flutter pub get, it gives this error:

Because project depends on flutter_lints any which doesn't exist (authorization failed), version solving failed.
Insufficient permissions to the resource at the https://pub.dev package repository.
You can modify credentials using:
dart pub token add https://pub.dev

It was not solved with vpn and dns.

Does flutter doctor -v show you have access to all central machines?

it shows everything is ok , there is no problem

are you trying to clear the cache?

I cleared cache, but after and before clearing I had this problem

Flutter in China > set mirrors > 403 dns> flutter clean > flutter pub get
It worked.
